# concrete example breaking xor encryption with five bits

Tags: encryption, cryptography

i am new to xor encryption and the task i have uses five bits not ascii. how do i break it?am looking for a concrete example of breaking.

Comment: How about a concrete problem?

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can't, you need to do statistical analysis on it.

You also need to know the key length, and make sure that the key length is shorter than the plaintext length, or you have a One-Time Pad, and that is unbreakable.

Answer (score 1):

For something this simple, brute force will probably work the best.   Write a program that just keeps adding to the xor key and looking for plaintext.